# What was the takeoff run distance of a Fw 200 Condor bomber/transport?

Tags: military, aircraft-performance, aviation-history

The [Fw 200 Condor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focke-Wulf_Fw_200_Condor) was a large plane of Germany during WW2. It was used in recon and bomber roles against convoys. Wikipedia lists several specs including max takeoff weight of 24.5 tons and 4 engines producing 895 kW each.

But I could not find takeoff run distance, neither there nor in google. I would like to know how long of a runway was needed for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately i could not find this information for the basic variants, but for the Fw200F an [Focke Wulf document](http://www.germanluftwaffe.com/archiv/Dokumente/ABC/f/FockeWulf/Fw%20200/Focke%20Wulf%20Fw%20200%20F.pdf) from 1943 states following

on a paved runway, 4x 323R engines on standard start power

```
********** (deleted / see graph)
```

on max power

```
   ********** (deleted / see graph)
```

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Link / photo of document? I can't find an Fw 200 **"F" variant,** 8,000 feet is insane distance for such plane.

Comment: the document is called  "Focke Wulf Fw 200 F Fernaufklärer mit erhöter Reichweite" page 29  http://www.germanluftwaffe.com/archiv/Dokumente/ABC/f/FockeWulf/Fw%20200/Focke%20Wulf%20Fw%20200%20F.pdf

Comment: excellent, but please double-check the numbers from the graph, I believe a mistake happened, at 25t I see 1000m for one of the lines, not 1450/1700.

Comment: ymb1: i think you are right, i got the scale wrong, another thing is the SR vs S20

Comment: @alfetta Yeah I'm curious: what does SR and S20 mean?

Comment: just a guess S20 could mean, run distance till reaching 20m flight height 
, this terms i found in an Cessna Handbuch  "Startrollstrecke"" and  "Startstrecke über 20m Hindernis" 
.

Comment: @alfetta - if I'm reading this right, the S20 is an obstacle of 20 m to be cleared, the double line for each is the density altitude / or power setting. I'm not 100% sure. Excellent find and +1.

Comment: @ymb1: yes, S20 looks to be the distance to reach 20m height, so with 1000hp / 25t some 1100m and 1050m with 1200hp // and with 1000hp / 25t some 800m for lifting of ground. we should remind, this document is a what if by Focke Wulf and the sheet is not based on some test at Reichlin AB

Comment: i found another document, the Fw 200 C-1 C-2 Kurzbetriebsanleitung.Teil 2.-Focke Wulf Flugzeugbau GmbH, on page II 06 the chapter FLUGBETRIEB describes how to start the plane and states with 21.300kg weight it needs 670m for lift off and 1550m for reaching 20m height

Answer (score 2):

The Fw 200 isn't really too large (even back then). A couple hundred were built during a time were many thousands of other types were built. So it's not very popular to easily find information about it online (trust me, I tried). More popular planes from that era lack that bit of information online as well.

The why is interesting, before the jet age, all you needed was a 6,000-foot runway and you were good to go (performance calculations were still performed, but you know what I mean, aircraft didn't need much runway until the jet age).

Based on Wikipedia, an aircraft of comparable role, configuration, and era is the [Douglas DC-4E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-4E) (almost same size by the way, and 4 big 1,080 kW engines).

From this [flightsafety.org report](https://www.flightsafety.org/ap/ap_jan00.pdf), we find the [Douglas C-54 Skymaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-54_Skymaster) (what became of the DC-4E via the DC-4) when loaded at 25.5 tonnes (the serendipity of the coincidence) needed 2,750 feet (839 m) of runway. That should apply more or less to the Fw 200.

**Note:** On a different day with less or more headwind, or a runway with a different slope, or any of the many variables, that number changes. Not to mention there were many Fw 200 *variants.*

If you need the figure for reasons other than curiosity, some sellers specialize in historic AFM's (aircraft flight manuals) where you will find all the performance information you need.

This should suffice unless a more specific answer comes along, which would need the variant and the exact runway specifications (elevation, slope, etc.), weather conditions, etc.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that a 6000 foot long runway was "crazy long" pre-jet age. Even some of the largest planes in service, like the L-1049 Super Constellation at a MTOW of more than 68 tons took less than 5000' of runway to take off.

Comment: @RonBeyer - I agree, I played it safe ;)